# What is this mobile navigation pattern called?

Tags: user-interface, mobile, user-experience

What is this mobile navigation pattern called? I need to replicate it but I dont even know how its called.

I need to replicate it in the mobile version of a responsive website. I believe its used in many native apps, its a "carousel" style navigation, where you slide the nav sideways in orther to access the other options.

[Mobile subnav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7epi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this particular pattern is called **Horizontal Overflow**. You can find an example of it under Brad Frost's Responsive Navigation Patterns (along with a ton of other great patterns) here:
https://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html#navigation

Answer (score 1):

In Android/Material Design that's a Tab.
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#

There is no identical native control on iOS, the closest thing is a Segmented Control placed at the top of a view.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW27

Their usage varies on the two platforms. On Android tabs navigate among a number of views, where on iOS top aligned Segmented Controls often provide a filtering function on a single view.

iOS has Tabs too, but they're properly positioned at the bottom of the screen.